changing the route list depending on the server port (swagger)
I would like to share routes that are already linked via tags via the "selected server".
{
  "openapi": "3.1.0",
  "info": {
    "title": "blue_traktor_api",
    "description": "This API handles various functionalities for USEPI, Icons, Dashboard, Settings, Patterns, Devices, Widgets, and more.",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "contact": {
      "name": "API Support",
      "url": "",
      "email": ""
    }
  },
  "servers": [
    {
      "url": "http://localhost:8000",
      "description": "TCP server for main operations"
    },
    {
      "url": "ws://localhost:8080",
      "description": "WebSocket server for updated parameters"
    }
  ],
  "paths": {...},
  "components":{...}
}

here is the first part of my openal file.json where I list servers. it will look like this: 

and I also have several routes for example:
  "paths": {
    "/api/usepi/patterns/create": {
      "post": {
        "tags": ["patterns"],
        "summary": "Create a new pattern",
        "operationId": "createPattern",
        "requestBody": {
          "required": true,
          "content": {
            "application/json": {
              "schema": {
                "$ref": "#/components/schemas/RequestStructure_PatternRequest"
              },
              "examples": {
                "PatternExample": {
                  "summary": "An example of a PatternRequest",
                  "value": {
                    "data": {
                      "id": null,
                      "title": "test",
                      "description": "test desc",
                      "icon": "http://localhost:8000/api/icons/test.svg",
                      "createDate": null,
                      "updateDate": null,
                      "favourite": false,
                      "data": {
                        "ID": {},
                        "QR-Code": {},
                        "Position": {},
                        "DeviceParams": {}
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "Pattern created.",
            "content": {
              "application/json": {
                "schema": {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/GoodResponse_Id"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "500": {
            "description": "Internal Server Error",
            "content": {
              "application/json": {
                "schema": {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/ErrorResponse"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }, ...
}

and there are still such routes, but with a different tag:
"/api/widgets/get": {
      "post": {
        "tags": ["widgets"],
        "summary": "Get widget details",
        "operationId": "getWidget",
        "requestBody": {
          "required": true,
          "content": {
            "application/json": {
              "schema": {
                "$ref": "#/components/schemas/RequestStructure_Id"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "Widget details.",
            "content": {
              "application/json": {
                "schema": {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/GoodResponse_GetWidgetResponse"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "500": {
            "description": "Internal Server Error",
            "content": {
              "application/json": {
                "schema": {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/ErrorResponse"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },

I would like that when selecting a server, only the routes associated with it are shown. for example, if http://localhost:8000 then /api/usepi/patterns/create ...
where I need to, I also got rid of the try it button and the parameter block in this way:
<script>
window.onload = function() {
    const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
      url: "http://localhost:8000/openai.json",
      dom_id: '#swagger-ui',
      deepLinking: true,
      presets: [
        SwaggerUIBundle.presets.apis,
        SwaggerUIStandalonePreset
      ],
      plugins: [
        SwaggerUIBundle.plugins.DownloadUrl
      ],
      layout: "StandaloneLayout"
    });

    window.ui = ui;

    function hideTryItOutButtons() {
      const pathsToDisable = [

        '#operations-patterns-createPattern > div.no-margin > div > div.opblock-section > div.opblock-section-header > div.try-out > button',
        '#operations-patterns-createPattern > div.no-margin > div > div.opblock-section > div.opblock-section-header',
        '#operations-patterns-createPattern > div.no-margin > div > div.opblock-section > div.parameters-container', ];

      pathsToDisable.forEach(selector => {
        const button = document.querySelector(selector);
        if (button) {
          button.style.display = 'none';
        }
      });
    }
    const observer = new MutationObserver(hideTryItOutButtons);
    observer.observe(document.getElementById('swagger-ui'), { childList: true, subtree: true });

    hideTryItOutButtons();
  };
</script>

This is what it looks like:

how can I make the display of only the necessary routes (like filter), if (as far as I remember) you can't do subtags for tags? show routes when selecting a server, also grouping by tags*

I solved this problem so that I didn't have to work on the error where, when hiding the list and switching to another option from the list of servers, the element disappears altogether.
"paths": {
    "/api/usepi/patterns/create": {
      "post": {
        "tags": ["patterns"],
        "summary": "http://localhost:8000",
        "operationId": "createPattern",
        "requestBody": {
          "required": true,
          "content": {
            "application/json": {
              "schema": {
                "$ref": "#/components/schemas/RequestStructure_PatternRequest"
              },
              "examples": {
                "PatternExample": {
                  "summary": "An example of a PatternRequest",
                  "value": {
                    "data": {
                      "id": null,
                      "title": "test",
                      "description": "test desc",
                      "icon": "http://localhost:8000/api/icons/Cтатическое оборудование/Статическое оборудование.svg",
                      "createDate": null,
                      "updateDate": null,
                      "favourite": false,
                      "data": {
                        "ID": {},
                        "QR-Code": {},
                        "Position": {},
                        "DeviceParams": {}
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "Pattern created.",
            "content": {
              "application/json": {
                "schema": {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/GoodResponse_Id"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "500": {
            "description": "Internal Server Error",
            "content": {
              "application/json": {
                "schema": {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/ErrorResponse"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },

in the "summary" I write down a variant from the list to determine which element of the list the route belongs to. Next, I look for matches in the list when drawing and delete what does not match the selected list value:

here is how it is implemented:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Swagger UI</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/swagger-ui/5.10.3/swagger-ui.css" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
  <style>
    body { background-color: #ffffff; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="swagger-ui"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/swagger-ui/5.10.3/swagger-ui-bundle.js" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/swagger-ui/5.10.3/swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script>
  window.onload = function() {
    const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
      url: "http://localhost:8000/openai.json",
      dom_id: '#swagger-ui',
      deepLinking: true,
      presets: [
        SwaggerUIBundle.presets.apis,
        SwaggerUIStandalonePreset
      ],
      plugins: [
        SwaggerUIBundle.plugins.DownloadUrl
      ],
      layout: "StandaloneLayout"
    });
    window.ui = ui;

    let isFiltering = false;

    function filterElements() {
      const selectElement = document.querySelector("#swagger-ui>section>div.swagger-ui>div:nth-child(2)>div.scheme-container>section>div>div>div>label>select");
      if (selectElement) {
        const selectedValue = selectElement.options[selectElement.selectedIndex].textContent.split(' - ')[0];
        console.log("Selected value from dropdown:", selectedValue);

        const parentCatalogs = document.querySelectorAll("#swagger-ui>section>div.swagger-ui>div:nth-child(2)>div:nth-child(4)>section>div>span> div > h3");
        console.log("Parent catalogs found:", parentCatalogs.length);

        parentCatalogs.forEach(parent => {
          const parentElement = parent.closest('div.opblock-tag-section');
          if (parentElement) {
            let childVisible = false;
            const childElements = parentElement.querySelectorAll("[id^='operations-']:not([id^='operations-tag'])");
            childElements.forEach(childElement => {
              const summaryControl = childElement.querySelector("button.opblock-summary-control > div > div");
              if (summaryControl) {
                const summaryText = summaryControl.textContent.trim();
                if (summaryText === selectedValue) {
                  childElement.style.display = '';
                  childVisible = true;
                  console.log(`---/Child Element ID: ${childElement.id} = ${summaryText}`);
                } else {
                  childElement.style.display = 'none';
                  console.log(`Hiding element with Child Element ID: ${childElement.id} as it does not match the selected value`);
                }
              } else {
                console.log(`Summary control not found for child element: ${childElement.id}`);
              }

              const elementsToRemove = childElement.querySelectorAll('.opblock-summary-description');
              elementsToRemove.forEach(element => {
                element.style.display = "none";
              });

              if (childElement.querySelectorAll('.no-margin').length > 0) {
                const opblock = childElement

                setTimeout(() => {
                  const elementToClear = opblock.querySelectorAll('.opblock-summary-path')
                  elementToClear.forEach(el => {
                    const dataPath = el.getAttribute('data-path').split('/').at(-1)
                    try { opblock.querySelectorAll('.opblock-description-wrapper')[0].remove() } catch {}
                    if (dataPath !== 'list' && dataPath !== 'icons' && dataPath !== '{path}') {
                      opblock.querySelectorAll('.opblock-section-header')[0].remove()
                    }
                  })
                }, 30)
              }
            });

            if (isFiltering) {
              if (!childVisible) {
                parentElement.style.display = 'none';
                console.log(`Hiding parent element as all child elements are hidden: ${parent.textContent}`);
              } else {
                parentElement.style.display = '';
              }
            }
          } else {
            console.log("Parent element not found for:", parent.textContent);
          }
        });
      } else {
        console.log("Select element not found.");
      }
    }

    document.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
      const selectElement = document.querySelector("#swagger-ui > section > div.swagger-ui > div:nth-child(2) > div.scheme-container > section > div > div > div > label > select");
      if (event.target === selectElement) {
        isFiltering = true;
        filterElements();
        isFiltering = false;
      }
    });

    document.addEventListener('click', () => {
        filterElements();
    });
    const observer = new MutationObserver(() => {
      const selectElement = document.querySelector("#swagger-ui > section > div.swagger-ui > div:nth-child(2) > div.scheme-container > section > div > div > div > label > select");
      if (selectElement) {
        isFiltering = true;
        filterElements();
        isFiltering = false;
        observer.disconnect();
      }
    });

    observer.observe(document.querySelector('#swagger-ui'), { childList: true, subtree: true });
  };
</script>
</body>
</html>


next question:
The collapse is not displayed when the selected element is changed

You can define the servers array at the each endpoint and that will limit the available server definition to the url. This uses the try-it out button you disabled.
I don't think Swagger-UI has an option to filter by servers in the manner you are asking.
Here's an example
{
    "openapi": "3.1.0",
    "info": {
        "title": "test",
        "version": "1"
    },
    "paths": {
        "/thing": {
            "servers": [{
                "description": "web sockets server",
                "url": "ws://localhost:8080"
            }],
            "get": {
                "responses": {
                    "200": {
                        "content": {
                            "application/json": {
                                "schema": {
                                    "$ref": "#/components/schemas/thing"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "/another_thing": {
            "servers": [{
                "description": "http server",
                "url": "http://localhost:8080"
            }],
            "get": {
                "responses": {
                    "200": {
                        "content": {
                            "application/json": {
                                "schema": {
                                    "$ref": "#/components/schemas/thing"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "components": {
        "schemas": {
            "thing": {}
        }
    }
}



